# IBM Worklight 6.0 - SRVE0777E: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I've just installed Worklight 6.0 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4.
I'm trying to build a very simple HelloWorklight app to test the installed environment and I'm getting errors building and deploying it.

I'm getting these errors in Eclipse console:

> [2013-07-13 02:11:21]             Starting build process: application
>   'HelloWorklightApp', all environments
>   [2013-07-13 02:11:21]             Application 'HelloWorklightApp' with
>   all environments build finished.
>   [2013-07-13 02:11:21]             Deploying application
>   'HelloWorklightApp' with all environments to Worklight Server...
>   [2013-07-13 02:11:21]             Failed to deploy the application to
>   Worklight server: Worklight module
>   HelloWorklightProject was not
>   successfully started. Full details of the error are available from the
>   Worklight Development Server console.

The Worklight Development Server console in my browser shows:

> Application Error
>   SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class
>   'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:110'
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
>   at  com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
>   at [internal classes]

I'm truly stuck. On the other hand I'm sure it must be something simple to fix it.
Has anyone got an idea how?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (at least WDS console error looks the same).

*A little bit history*:

My problems started, when I updated Worklight to version 6 (with version 5 I had no problems). Some compilation erros were fixed by [adding Websphere Library](http://mobilemainframe.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/worklight-5-0-5-project-migration-to-worklight-6-errors/) to a project. But my custom authentication still wasn't working.

*How I fixed it*:

- open new workspace in Eclipse
- import Worklight project
- clean project
- restart Eclipse
- downgrade compiler compliance level (in Eclipse: Window > Preferences > Compiler and set "Compiler compliance level" to lower version)
- rebuild project and try to run it

At this point it started to work. I've spend lots of time to find out that compiler stuff, but still I'm not sure which part requires that.

Answer (score 1):

So we had this issue with 2 macs and it took us a solid day and a half to figure it all out.
We went through a lot of reconfiguring, re-downloading eclipse and worklight.

1. Make sure your config files from the update are correct. (worklight.prop and authConfig)
2. This is the big one. **Install JDK 1.7 and reference the new JRE 7**. When we
   were running on Oracle JRE 6, we had a ton of errors and even a Java
   Heap memory issue.

Once you install it, it may to be tricky to find the actually path to the JRE.

**First, go to Eclipse > Pref > Installed JRE's > Add**

Then, add a new standard vm. Click Directory on the next pane and browse to the install path of JRE.

**We found it in [name of your HD] > Library > Java > JavaVirtualMachines > jdk1.7.0_25.jdk > Contents > Home > jre**

It should load everything it needs and you can click the check box of the new JRE. For good measure, I changed the compiler to 1.7 as well.

The jdk folder may have a slightly diff name depending on what update you have. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after deploy an new app deployment.

What I've done on Server is:

- delete all application
- delete all extra configuration between new server instance and my current instance. In my case it was: applicationMonitor and shared librairy
- clean
- restart

After that I managed to deploy my application normally

Answer (score 0):

window -> show view -> servers -> server configuration -> HTTP EndPoint -> host

By default the host will be *. Try to change the host as your local machine ip address. for example host = . After changing the host, close the server.xml and then try to rebuild the project.