# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Can't initialize Worklight Project when deploying to production server

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to deploy a project to WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile.
After added the war to server/apps folder I configured server.xml as shown on the page below:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdeploy%2Fc_deploy_custom_war_file_to_app_server.html

But when I try to open it on the browser I get this error:

```
 Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:110'
javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]
```

I'm using JRE6 both to compile and on server.

Comment: Full Worklight verion? (that is, build number...)

Comment: I'm using WorklightStudioPlugin 6.0.0.20130926-1933 to develop and I'm deploying to a WebSphere 8.5.5.0

Comment: Any logs from the application server?

Comment: This is what appears on `console.log`: [ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
        at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
        at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized
        ... 4 more

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a common exception that is thrown.

More detailed info can be found in the log files in your was liberty folder.

For us it was the following:

- jre 6 was used instead of 7
- in the xml configuration file several jars are referenced but did not exist on the referenced location
- added jndi references to the configuration file (3 references to 3 different db's)
- worklight databases weren't set up properly

It took us 1,5 day for figuring out why it didn't work.

There is a big document of several 100's of pages available somewhere which describes all steps you have to follow to configure the server. It contains sql scripts to execute on the db, description of the server.xml file and so on.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I NEED to use jre 7 on WebSphere? Even if I compile with java6? If yes, is there an easy way to update the server jre? It seems that WebSphere doesn't use the system jre (because its already the 7) and it use its own java (found on `WebSphere/Toolbox/java`).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I lost track of this thread. We did complile in 7, so we needed 7. I think if you compile in 6, you should only have jre 6 available. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Related topics (same error message):

- [WorkLighr 6.0 Deployement on windows 8 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701720/worklighr-6-0-deployement-on-windows-8-issue)
- [Worklight 6.0 does not start on Liberty - HSQLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060671/worklight-6-0-does-not-start-on-liberty-hsqldb)
- [IBM Worklight - Error while trying to deploy application/adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761233/ibm-worklight-error-while-trying-to-deploy-application-adapter)
- [IBM Worklight 6.0 - SRVE0777E: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619425/ibm-worklight-6-0-srve0777e-javax-servlet-servletexception-worklight-project)

Common culprits:

- Misconfigured authenticationConfig.xml
- Using JRE6

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i didn't touch `authenticationConfig.xml`, using all standard configurations. And about the JRE, copying my comment on @Lvdd answer:Do I NEED to use jre 7 on WebSphere? Even if I compile with java6? If yes, is there an easy way to update the server jre? It seems that WebSphere doesn't use the system jre (because its already the 7) and it use its own java (found on WebSphere/Toolbox/java)